# Keycloak Logout with SAML

Tags: saml, keycloak

I got a problem with logout using saml protocol in Keycloak Server 4.2.1.
Next to the Keycloak there is a Wildfly 9 server. In the Wildfly Server there 
are serveral .war files deployed. They are JSF Applications with JEE7.

I configured the saml adapter (keycloak-saml.xml) like this. Similiar to the documetation 
(https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_saml-general-config)

```
<keycloak-saml-adapter>
   <SP entityID="amp"
      sslPolicy="EXTERNAL"
      logoutPage="logout.jsp">
      <Keys>
        <Key signing="true">
            <PrivateKeyPem>
                ...CLIENT PRIVATE KEY...
            </PrivateKeyPem>
            <CertificatePem>
                ...CLIENT CERTIFICATE ...
            </CertificatePem>
        </Key>
    </Keys>
    <PrincipalNameMapping policy="FROM_ATTRIBUTE"/>
    <IDP entityID="idp"
         signatureAlgorithm="RSA_SHA256"
         signatureCanonicalizationMethod="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
        <SingleSignOnService signRequest="true"
                             validateResponseSignature="true"
                             requestBinding="POST"
                             bindingUrl="http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/My-Realm/protocol/saml"/>
        <SingleLogoutService signRequest="true"
                             signResponse="true"
                             validateRequestSignature="true"
                             validateResponseSignature="true"
                             requestBinding="POST"
                             responseBinding="POST"
                             postBindingUrl="http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/My-Realm/protocol/saml"
                             redirectBindingUrl="http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/My-Realm/protocol/saml"/>
        <Keys>
            <Key signing="true">
                <CertificatePem>
                    ... REALM CERTIFICATE ...
                </CertificatePem>
            </Key>
        </Keys>
    </IDP>
</SP>
</keycloak-saml-adapter>
```

When i click the "logout button" the application calls
the code below so that the Wildfly server invalidate the session.

```
((HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest()).logout();
((HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false)).invalidate();
```

I checked it and its working, the application is invalidate the session.

Now after that, i have to tell the keycloak server that he should invalidate this session too.
Which URL I have to call?

```
 FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(" ???? ");
```

Before I migrated to Keycloak Server 4.2.1, I had the older version 1.8.1 running.
With the 1.8.1 Server I called the URL

"http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/My-Realm/tokens/logout?redirect_uri=http://localhost:8180/amp".

But that is not working anymore.

I have tested serveral URL but none of them are working. I checked the latest 
documetation https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#logout-2
and the parameter GLO=true is not working either.
I also tried to configure "Logout Service POST Binding URL" and "Logout Service Redirect Binding URL" 
for the client in the keycloak adminstration console.

Did i miss something in code or adminstration console of keycloak? 
Do i have to call a specific url in keycloak 4.2.1?

If you need more informations, let me know.

Thanks for your help.

kind regards.

Comment: Hey,

i'm calling the global Logout url.

I configured the "Logout Service POST Binding URL" and "Logout Service Redirect Binding URL"
to the adress: http://localhost:8180/MY_APP_NAME/ for the client in the keycloak server.

And in my code im calling:```java
FacesContext context = getCurrentInstance();
((HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest()).logout()((HttpSession) context.getExternalContext().getSession(false)).invalidate();
   
context.getExternalContext().redirect("http://localhost:8180/MY_APP_NAME/saml/logout?GLO=true");``` Sorry for the horrible format..

Answer (score 2):

Keycloak provides a single SAML endpoint, namely '*https://{host}/realms/{realm}/protocol/saml*', to which you have to send the SAML logout request. In your client SAML configuration, you either have to setup the "Master SAML Processing URL" pointing to your application's SAML endpoint, or you have to explicitly configure the "Logout Service Redirect Binding URL" if you have a special SAML endpoint for Single Logout in your application.

Comment: A comment on your question was posted as answer: "The SAML endpoint changed to **https://{host}/realms/{realm}/protocol/saml** See: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#keycloak-server-saml-uri-endpoints"